# Stripe Checkout in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe.js

I'm using Stripe Checkout in my React App.  Somehow I'm not passing the properties to my onToken function correctly as I'm getting not defined errors.

I eventually need to send a bunch of props, but for now just trying to get it to work correctly.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';

const PAYMENT_SERVER_URL = '3RD_PARTY_SERVER';
const CURRENCY = 'USD';

export default class Stripe25 extends React.Component {

  onToken = (token) => {
    axios.post(PAYMENT_SERVER_URL,
        {
          description,
          source: token.id,
          currency: CURRENCY,
          amount: amount
        })
        .then(successPayment)
        .catch(errorPayment);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StripeCheckout
        token={this.onToken}
        stripeKey="STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"
        name=""
        description=""
        image=""
        panelLabel="Donate"
        amount={2500} // cents
        currency="USD"
        locale="auto"
        zipCode={false}
        billingAddress={true}
      >
      <button className="btn btn-primary">
        $25
      </button>
    </StripeCheckout>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is description defined? I don't see it anywhere, and it isn't passed into the onToken method.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `source: token.id` to `source: token && token.id`.

The token may not yet be defined when you are trying to set the id. This is often an issue with dot chaining in an async environment.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  However, I'm getting the error on description before I even get to token.  When I submit the Stripe Checkout I am getting to errors.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () https://checkout.stripe.com/api/color?image_url=&key=&locale=en-US
*removed private information

and

Uncaught ReferenceError: description is not defined
    at TokenCallback.r.onToken [as fn] (Contribute.3fc54992.js:13)
    at TokenCallback.trigger (checkout.js:3)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, in your onToken method, the only available variable is token. But you're also referencing description and amount, neither of which are available anywhere in the scope from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass description and amount into your onToken constant. You can see an example of this as well as how to pass Shipping information into Stripe in this article:

[Send Shipping Info to Stripe with React-Stripe-Checkout](https://medium.com/@tfogg2/react-stripe-checkout-and-shipping-information-870f2d7d0705)

The solution will look like this:

```
const onToken = (amount, description) => (token, args) =>
  axios.post(PAYMENT_SERVER_URL,
    {
      description,
      source: token.id,
      currency: CURRENCY,
      amount: fromDollarToCent(amount),
      metadata: args
    })
    .then(successPayment)
    .catch(errorPayment);
```

The (token, **args**) and **metadata: args** are optional incase you want to pass shipping information into Stripe.

Comment: Hi! Though the answer may be in the link you provided, it is useful to see an actual example of how to solve the questions.